# .gif images not showing animation, Here I am setting .gif image in ImageView

Tags: objective-c

.gif images not showing animation, Here  I am setting .gif image in ImageView.
    Here is my code. I have these .gif Images in my project.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 NBoostDetailCell *cell = (NBoostDetailCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"gifCell"];

 [cell imgViewgif].animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:[cellData valueForKey:@"gifImage"]], nil];
        [cell imgViewgif].animationDuration = 0.5f;
        [cell imgViewgif].animationRepeatCount = 100;
        [[cell imgViewgif] startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage)  see if it works for you..

Comment: FLAnimatedImage *image = [FLAnimatedImage animatedImageWithGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[cellData valueForKey:@"gifImage"]]]]; NSLog(@"%@", image); I tried this but it is nil in image.